# FromRow instance for nested type with postgresql-simple

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I am using the following types to represent a user:

```hs
data CredentialsRep uType pType = Credentials { username :: uType
                                              , password :: pType } deriving (Show)

data NameRep fType lType = Name { first :: fType
                                , last  :: lType } deriving (Show)

data UserRep cType nType = User { credentials :: cType
                                , name        :: nType} deriving (Show)
```

How can I write the `FromRow` instance for `UserRep` so that `postgresql-simple` can turn my queries into useful types? So far, I have this:

```hs
instance FromRow (UserRep a b) where
  fromRow = do
    username <- field
    password <- field
    fname <- field
    lname <- field
    return $ (User (Credentials username password) (Name fname lname))
```

Which results in this error:

```hs
src/PSQLTEST.hs:30:5:
    Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘CredentialsRep uType0 pType0’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at src/PSQLTEST.hs:24:10
    Expected type: RowParser (UserRep a b)
      Actual type: RowParser
                     (UserRep (CredentialsRep uType0 pType0) (NameRep fType0 lType0))
    Relevant bindings include
      password :: pType0 (bound at src/PSQLTEST.hs:27:5)
      username :: uType0 (bound at src/PSQLTEST.hs:26:5)
      fromRow :: RowParser (UserRep a b) (bound at src/PSQLTEST.hs:25:3)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      return $ (User (Credentials username password) (Name fname lname))
    In the expression:
      do { username <- field;
           password <- field;
           fname <- field;
           lname <- field;
           .... }
    In an equation for ‘fromRow’:
        fromRow
          = do { username <- field;
                 password <- field;
                 fname <- field;
                 .... }

src/PSQLTEST.hs:30:5:
    Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘NameRep fType0 lType0’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at src/PSQLTEST.hs:24:10
    Expected type: RowParser (UserRep a b)
      Actual type: RowParser
                     (UserRep (CredentialsRep uType0 pType0) (NameRep fType0 lType0))
    Relevant bindings include
      lname :: lType0 (bound at src/PSQLTEST.hs:29:5)
      fname :: fType0 (bound at src/PSQLTEST.hs:28:5)
      fromRow :: RowParser (UserRep a b) (bound at src/PSQLTEST.hs:25:3)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      return $ (User (Credentials username password) (Name fname lname))
    In the expression:
      do { username <- field;
           password <- field;
           fname <- field;
           lname <- field;
           .... }
    In an equation for ‘fromRow’:
        fromRow
          = do { username <- field;
                 password <- field;
                 fname <- field;
                 .... }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I haven't used this library at all)

You're trying to define `FromRow` for all `UserRep a b`, but in the definition of `fromRow` you're explicitly constructing a `UserRep (CredentialsRep u p) (NameRep f l)`, hence the error saying it can't match `a` with `CredentialsRep u p` and `b` with `NameRep f l` (modulo type variable names).  Instead, I believe you can do something like

```hs
instance (FromField u, FromField p, FromField f, FromField l) => FromRow (UserRep (CredentialsRep u p) (NameRep f l)) where
    fromRow = do
        username  <- field
        password  <- field
        firstname <- field
        lastname  <- field
        return $ User (Credentials username password) (Name firstname lastname)
```

Or just

```hs
instance FromRow (UserRep (CredentialsRep String String) (NameRep String String)) where
    ...
```

with the same `fromRow` definition. With this approach you may have to enable the `FlexibleInstances` extension.

In addition, it looks like you may be making your types too polymorphic (but your situation might be unique, take this advice with a grain of salt), you could just get rid of the type parameters altogether and have

```hs
data CredentialsRep = Credentials
    { username :: String
    , password :: String
    } deriving (Show)

data NameRep = Name
    { first :: String
    , last :: String
    } deriving (Show)

data UserRep = User
    { credentials :: CredentialsRep
    , name :: NameRep
    } deriving (Show)
```

In which case you would just need

```hs
instance FromRow UserRep where
    ...
```

with the same `fromRow` definition.

Comment: Regarding your two suggestions, I tried to use that solution as well, but GHC complains: `Illegal instance declaration for ‘FromRow (UserRep (CredentialsRep u p) (NameRep f l))’ (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an) where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*, ....`. The reason I am using such polymorphic types is so I can represent user validation by swapping out `String`s that represent the actual values with `Maybe String`s that represent a potential error (for example a weak password).

Comment: @broma0 I believe you can get that error to go away with the `FlexibleInstances` extension, which is entirely non-controversial and very common in practice.  Just put `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` at the top of your source file.

Comment: You got it. I edited your answer to mention `FlexibleInstances`. Thank you!